# C# DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() Always Get Same Data in short period

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Example Code:
.net core 3

```
await Task.Delay( 1000 );

Console.WriteLine( "Hello World!!!!!!!!!" + DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() );

await Task.Delay( 1000 );

Console.WriteLine( "Hello World!!!!!!!!!" + DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() );

Console.WriteLine( "Hello World!!!!!!!!!" + DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() );

Console.WriteLine( "Hello World!!!!!!!!!" + DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() );

Console.WriteLine( "Hello World!!!!!!!!!" + DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() );

Console.WriteLine( "Hello World!!!!!!!!!" + DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() );

await Task.Delay( 1000 );

Console.WriteLine( "Hello World!!!!!!!!!" + DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() );

Console.WriteLine( "Hello World!!!!!!!!!" + DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() );

Console.WriteLine( "Hello World!!!!!!!!!" + DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() );

Console.WriteLine( "Hello World!!!!!!!!!" + DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() );
```

Expect to get different number , but all the same if without any delay.

I wonder how could this happened?
[image: testPicture]

Comment: The numbers after the Task.Delay seem to be different. The numbers between two Task.Delays are the same because the code takes less than one millisecond to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows is not a real-time operating system. It has a system clock resolution of 15.6ms.

> The default timer resolution on Windows is 15.6 ms – a timer interrupt 64 times a second.

[https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/windows-timer-resolution-megawatts-wasted/#:~:text=The%20default%20timer%20resolution%20on,consumption%20and%20harm%20battery%20life](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/windows-timer-resolution-megawatts-wasted/#:%7E:text=The%20default%20timer%20resolution%20on,consumption%20and%20harm%20battery%20life).

Your code is running faster than the system updates.

Comment: The resolution may be (and is frequently) changed by applications on Windows, and it is platform dependent now that .NET is no longer limited to Windows, therefore writing that "it has a system clock resolution of 15.6ms" is not really accurate.

Comment: @Lucero - Do you have a reference to show how apps change it? I did also specify Windows in the same paragraph as my "is has a" statement.

Comment: Sure... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod?redirectedfrom=MSDN and http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FUndocumented%20Functions%2FTime%2FNtSetTimerResolution.html for instance.

Answer (score 1):

For one the code executes very fast, so that this can indeed all be in the same millisecond between the delays.

However, that is not the only issue. The clock has a certain resolution, which can depend on the platform. On Windows, for instance, resolution is 10..15ms, so that increments are not visible every millisecond.

This is also documented in the documentation for [`DateTime.UtcNow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.utcnow?view=net-6.0#remarks).

For more exact measurements, have a look at the [Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-6.0) class.